# Install aquarea2mqtt on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, ssh, mqtt

Im new on Linux/Raspberry Pi and I have some problem with installing program from a file. Can You help me with that?
I need this project implemented in my Home Assistant (to view my heat pomp)
https://github.com/lsochanowski/Aquarea2mqtt
It has EXE, linux 64 and arm8 versions. Arm8 is for Raspberry Pi right?
How Can I install it via SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this program is written in Go, and has a compiled binary for ARM v8 in the repository (as well as for Windows, and Intel 64-bit Linux)

You can download the ARM v8 binary by clicking on the link for the file and then clicking the Download button on the page. This will download the file. You’ll need to transfer that to your Pi (if you are not on the Pi when you download it). You’ll also need to make it executable using `chmod +x Aquarea2Mqtt-lin-arm8`.

Finally, you’ll need a file called `config` in the same directory as the binary - the repository has documentation on how to configure it. I do not have one of these Panasonic devices.

I ran the executable on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2 running Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye and it *seemed* to work (but failed to connect as I didn’t have a valid password in the config file).

If this does not work, you may need to compile the code yourself using Go. If you’re not technical / you’re new at this, it might not be as straightforward as all that, and there is no compile or run instructions in the README file, so you may be best asking the author or current project maintainer.